# JAVA: How to verify if clicked item is different from previously clicked one?

Tags: java

I have multiple JLabels and all of them have a common MouseListener().
Now on MouseClicked() even I want to verify if the currently clicked JLabel is different from and only from the previous one, how do I do that?
I know I can simply do something like "if(e.getSource() != from label_1)", but since the labels won't be precreated, but newly created each time from another class, I need a verification method that is not based on known variables, but that actually checks if the current source is different from the previous one.
This is the mouseClicked method

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mapPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel temp = (JLabel) e.getSource();

    if (!clicked) {

        mapPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 650));
        add(mapPanel);
        System.out.println(clicked);
        clicked = true;
        temp.removeMouseListener(this);
        mapPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    // if(temp.pr)
    else {
        System.out.println(clicked);
        remove(mapPanel);
        temp.addMouseListener(this);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 150));
        mapPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        clicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the previous source in a variable and compare `e.getSource()` to that. Then store `e.getSource()` into the same variable to prepare for the next click.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Pretty smart roundaway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since my comment solved your problem, I'm re-posting it here as an answer. ☺

Store the previous source in a field and compare `e.getSource()` to that. Then store `e.getSource()` into the same variable to prepare for the next click.